# How do I display text based on a condition?

Tags: excel

I feel like I'm missing something here but can't find out what. I'm creating a planning template. I want a separate table in which the user can put the deadline name with the deadline week.

In my planning overview I want these deadlines to appear. To do this, I tried an approach with `IF()`-statements. Although this works well, it doesn't deal with a new deadline that is added later on in the project.
I could brute force this and create 30 `IF()`-statements so there's space for 30 deadlines (which is more than enough) but I have a feeling this can be done in a much smoother way. Do you have any suggestions for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX`/`MATCH`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A;MATCH(E2;$B:$B;0));"")
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, I knew there had to be a better way to handle this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have not used the function `vlookup` before.
Vlookup is one of essential functions in excel and learning & starting use of it will definitely make you a better excel user and save you lots of time later on.

You can solve your puzzle via `vlookup` as described below:
Swap the columns "name" & "week".  Week will be in col A, Concept in col B.
Write this formula to cell E1 and then you can paste it to F1 to N1:
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E$2;$A$2:$B$50;2;FALSE);"")`